How can I resolve the Yolov8 Frame rate on real time camera video feed?
How can I resolve the Yolov8 Frame rate on real time camera video feed ?
However, when executing the code, there is a noticeable lag of about 5 seconds. What are the potential causes of this lag, and what optimizations or adjustments can I make to achieve smoother, real-time performance?
What could be the potential solution to resolve this problem ? Any suggestion or link will be helpful

In order to Making Real Time Video Inference without making video lag. I would recommend you to look into deep streamer for Yolo. It provide very high performance on the Real Time Object Detection and Inference.
I have used this to detect objects in real time on many of the Input Camera Streams. You can find the Example Code in the Repo.
Here the link: https://github.com/marcoslucianops/DeepStream-Yolo

Thanks for sharing the deep streamer, can you please point some example code ?
